# How can I get arround Ocaml's type error?

Tags: ocaml

I have this warning and I would like to know why he wait an expression of type `Unix.file_descr list * Unix.file_descr list * Unix.file_descr list`

Here is the function, if you need more code, just ask me.

```
let rec run()=

 let a = create_bloc() in
 trace_bloc(a);
 let b : char ref = ref 'f' in
 while true do
 b := 'f';
 if !(a.s) = 1 then run() else
   let c = get_move() in
   if c = Some 'z' then b:= 'z'
   else if c = Some 'q' then b:= 'q'
   else if c = Some 's' then b:= 's'
   else if c = Some 'd' then b:= 'd';
   if !b = 'z' || !b = 's' then
     if !(a.o) = 4 && !b = 'z' then begin erase_bloc(a) ;a.o := 1; trace_bloc(a); end
     else if !b = 'z' && !(a.o) <> 4 then begin erase_bloc(a); a.o := !(a.o)+1; end;
   if !b = 's' && !(a.o)=1 then begin erase_bloc(a);a.o := 4;trace_bloc(a);end else
     if !b = 's' && !(a.o) <> 1 then begin erase_bloc(a); a.o := !(a.o)-1;trace_bloc(a);end
     else if !b = 'd' || !b = 'q' then
       decal(a,!b);
   dep_bas(a);
   Unix.select [] [] [] 0.35;
 done;
;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Unix.file_descr list * Unix.file_descr list * Unix.file_descr list` type is the type of a value that is retuned by the expression `Unix.select [] [] [] 0.35;`

OCaml doesn't allow you to ignore a value returned by a function that has a type other than `unit`. You can, however, use the `ignore` function to tell explicitly to the compiler that you don't need the result of the `select` function,

```ml
ignore (Unix.select [] [] [] 0.35);
```

You can also use `Unix.sleepf` function to implement sleeping that supports fractions of seconds, e.g., you can substitute the above expression with just,

```
Unix.sleepf 0.35
```

This will as well pause your program for 350 milliseconds.